# How do I write this test case?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit4

I am currently doing a small project on spring-mvc in my backend and I am trying to create tests for my converters and engines. Below is my `BookmarkEngine.java` file

```
@Service
public class BookmarkEngine implements IBookmarkEngine{

    private static final String URL_PREFIX = "http://";

    @Override
    public String getFullUrl(String url) {
        if(!url.startsWith(URL_PREFIX))
        {
            return URL_PREFIX + url;
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

How would I go about writing a test for this?

Here is my BookmarkEngineTest:

```
public class BookmarkEngineTest {

    IBookmarkEngine bookmarkEngine = new BookmarkEngine();
    private ViewBookmark defaultBookmark;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        defaultBookmark = new ViewBookmark();
        defaultBookmark.setBookmarkId(1L);
        defaultBookmark.setTitle("A sample bookmark");
        defaultBookmark.setUrl("This is a sample bookmark.");
        defaultBookmark.setAuthor(".");
        defaultBookmark.setLastUpdated(1497812309081L);
    }

    @Test
    public void getFullUrl() {
        String result = bookmarkEngine.getFullUrl(defaultBookmark.getUrl());
        assertThat(result.length(), is(defaultBookmark.getUrl().length()));
    }
}
```

That certain test in getFullUrl() does not run, but how can I can make it work?

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that, I'm using JUnit 4+ testing.

Comment: It seems you really don't understand what you're doing. A test is supposed to verify that the code does what it's supposed to do. So, what is this method supposed to do? If it's correct, it's supposed to add http:// to a string, unless the string already starts with http://. That's what the test must verify. 1. Pass "foo.bar.com", and check it returns "http://foo.bar.com". Then pass "http://foo.bar.com", and check it still returns "http://foo.bar.com". No need for any ViewBookmark, which is completely irrelevant, and the length of the returned string is  irrelevant, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a test to see if the strings will match such as

```
@Test
public void getFullUrl() {
String testurl = "facebook.com";
String testurl2 = "http://facebook.com";
assertEquals(bookmarkEngine.getFullUrl(testurl),"http://facebook.com");
assertEquals(bookmarkEngine.getFullUrl(testurl2),"http://facebook.com");
}
```